# How do you get the contact information for a Foursquare user who checks in to your venue via 4sq's API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I am currently writing an application as the owner of a particular venue. I want to be able to programmatically reach out to a user who checks in to the location via the contact information associated with their Foursquare account (if they've chosen to make that information public).

Based on the sample code provided with the [Real-Time API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime), it doesn't look like contact information is returned here. Is there a way to crawl to the necessary info from the info returned via this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You generally ought to actually be able to get the email from the actual push API response. Inside the `user` object should be a `contact` object, and the `email` field will be populated with their email. You can always also fall back to making a [user details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users) call to retrieve a user's contact info once you know their user ID.

However, please keep in mind our [API platform policy](https://foursquare.com/legal/api/platformpolicy) when it comes to situations like this. From the policy: "You must not take any action that constitutes unauthorized or unsolicited advertising, junk or bulk e-mail."